# Odd text characters after parsing from JSON file? Encoding issue?

Tags: r, json, encode

I have a JSON file with Tweet data, containing fields such as text, published date, author, ID, etc.

I used the parseTweets function from streamR, but when I view the completed df, the text has not been encoded/parsed in correctly.

```
tweets <- parseTweets("C:/Users/...file.json",simplify = FALSE, verbose = TRUE, legacy = FALSE)
View(tweets)
```

This is what is shown in the "text" column of the parsed object

```
think youâ€™re continuing the conversation
```

It should say: think you're continuing the conversation

I did some searching and this seems to be an encoding issue, but I can't seem to figure it out.
Would I need to parseTweets first, then edit the text column afterwards? Or is there a wrapper method that I can parse correctly the first time I read in the JSON? 
Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Here is an example JSON snippet pulled from my larger file

```
{"created_at":"Sun Jun 10 00:01:12 +0000 2018","id":100565760896,"id_str":"1005600896","text":"think you’re continuing the conversation","source":"<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone</a>","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":403340,"id_str":"40311840","name":"Dvo","screen_name":"ImBorau","location":"Florida, USA","url":"http://Instagram.com/ ","description":"ucf | I your sarcastic quips","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":43,"friends_count":166,"listed_count":0,"favourites_count":839,"statuses_count":1460,"created_at":"Wed Nov 02 01:41:45 +0000 2011","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":true,"lang":null,"contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"9AE4E8","profile_background_image_url":"http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme16/bg.gif","profile_background_image_url_https":"https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme16/bg.gif","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"0084B4","profile_sidebar_border_color":"BDDCAD","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDFFCC","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/10014987138688/RYbZNdVR_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/100149871633688/RYbNdVR_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/40318340/107757914","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null,"updated":["description","name"]},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":{"id":"4ec0163497","url":"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/4ec1c9db497.json","place_type":"admin","name":"Florida","full_name":"Florida, USA","country_code":"US","country":"United States","bounding_box":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-87.634643,24.396308],[-87.634643,31.001056],[-79.974307,31.001056],[-79.974307,24.396308]]]},"attributes":{}},"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"quote_count":0,"reply_count":0,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1528588108","matching_rules":[{"tag":null,"id":484862573421,"id_str":"48486970421"}]}
```

Comment: "*Unfortunately, I cannot provide sample code for confidentiality reasons.*" - you could easily provide a small snippet of *json* that has removed identifying details.

Comment: @thelatemail You're right, I added a snippet without any personal information

Comment: `’` looks like a 'smart quote' character, distinct from `'`. Should be solvable if it could be processed as UTF-8, but I can't see any way to specify encoding in `parseTweets`. Maybe you could read the text into R first using `readLines` with an `encoding=` specified and pass that object to `parseTweets` then. I'm not able to test that currently, but thought I'd at least give an idea.